# Two Mercedes Electronic Keys - One Works As a Remote - One Works to Start The Car - How Can These Be Combined?

Tags: mercedes-benz, key, keyless-entry, smartkey

I just bought a 2005 Mercedes C230 and I have two Mercedes electronic keys - one works as a remote - one works to start the car - how can these be combined/programmed so they are both fully functional?

Comment: By remote, you mean to unlock the doors, not remotely start the car?

Comment: Can you post a pic? Sometimes the luxury brands provide a valet key, so your locked compartments remain locked.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to have the keys programmed to the car. The only way to do that is to take it to the dealership. They have the necessary tools which are proprietary. Only they have them. Yes, it's a racket.